# Ninja form Select-All Unselect-All checkbox button not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, checkbox, multipartform-data, ninja-forms

I am working on multi-select ninja form. In the first step there are 8 checkbox options and client want a button for Select all unselect all. I am trying to checked all checkbox option on button click using jquery but in Ninja form checkbox only post values when some one click on it. By jquery, checked all checkbox option did not pass any values on form submit.
https://prnt.sc/10xygiq